# what does "give sth a go" means?

Tags: idioms

I am online freelancer and working with a international software team.

Just a while ago, my partner commented my issues on github as shown below.

> Just looking back at history of package.json it looks like the
>   cordova-android: > 6.2.0 requirement was added in 0.8.4.
>
> 0.8.3 doesn't have it. **Maybe give that a go**.

Please help me to understand more clearly.

Comment: It means to try something. In your case: try version 0.8.3, because it does not have the mentioned requirement.

Comment: Does it means the same with "Please try with this version"?

Comment: Yes, it means precisely that.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Please, Folks, be more careful. In general yes, "Give it a go" means simply "Try it." 

Specifically all that about "cordova-android: > 6.2.0 requirement was added in 0.8.4.” and “0.8.3 doesn't have it" add only confusion.

Comment: English has no such word as “sth”. Please write what you mean.